# Adding bits at specific indexes for a uint8_t block

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I have a pointer to a `uint8_t` array in the form of:

```
uint8_t* array; // 64-bit array
```

I need to modify this array by shifting bits to the right and inserting a bit of 0 or 1 at indexes with a power of 2. Thereby generating a 72-bit array.

```
uint8_t newArr[9];
```

What is the best way to modify an array so I can add the bits at the specific places I computed. I thought of converting the array to a a char array and then adding the bits one by one. However, is there a faster and more easier method than this.

So if I have a pointer to a bit array in the form of `uint8_t` like:

```
000100001 11001111 01101101 11000001 11100000 00101111 11111001 10010010
```

I would need to modify it into a `uint8_t[9]` array so that I insert bits I have specified at 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 of the new array to look like: (answer is wrong)

```
00000000 11001111 11001111 11001111 11001111 01101101 01101101 10010010 00100001
```

But I don't know how to shift a particular bit to the right without shifting all the bits. For example if I shift all bits starting at index 2 1 to the right and then all bits starting from index 4 to the right by one.

Comment: Which way is right, higher addresses in memory or lower? Do you really only want to insert bits at indices with a power of 2—1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and so on? You never want to insert a bit at an index that is 17 or 26? Or are you saying, at one time, you have six bits that you want to insert at indices 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32? There is no point in converting the array to a `char` array; an array of `uint8_t` is effectively a `char` array, except for sign issues (for which `uint8_t` is better anyway). There will not be a good way of dealing with this; you will have to shift at the bit level.

Comment: So if i take a uint8_t array at a time lets say at index 0 for the example I get 00010001 which represents 8 bits. I would need to insert a bit I have computed at indexes 0, 2 and 4. Which means I need to right shift by 3 places. But after I right shift once then I lose the 8th bit which needs to carry over. This is not the only problem. The next time I need to right shift by 1 so I can insert a bit at index 2, I lose the bit at index 1 which needs to be non changed

Comment: @ChanakaPerera First figure out where all the bits need to go. Start with `aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb ... gggggggg hhhhhhhh` and then insert bits. For example `gggggggg hhhhhhhh` becomes `ggghhhh8 hhh4h210`. So you need to chop the `h` byte into three pieces and shift the pieces to the correct positions.

Comment: I found a method by using a char array of 72 size to get the solution using 0 and 1's. Now I need to somehow transform it back into a uint8_t array of size 9.

Comment: `uint8_t result=0; for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) result= (result << 1) | array[i];` will convert an array of size 8 into a single `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 3):

Say you start with the following:

```
src[0]   src[1]   src[2]   src[3]   src[4]   src[5]   src[6]   src[7]
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
       7        6        5        4        3        2        1
76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210
aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc dddddddd eeeeeeee ffffffff gggggggg hhhhhhhh
```

You want to insert at the following positions (octal):
0, 1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40, 100

That means you want the following:

```
dst[0]   dst[1]   dst[2]   dst[3]   dst[4]   dst[5]   dst[6]   dst[7]   dst[8]
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
       1
       0        7        6        5        4        3        2        1
76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210 76543210
aaaaaaa0 abbbbbbb bccccccc cddddddd deeeeee0 eeffffff ffggggg0 ggghhhh0 hhh0h000
```

So,

```
dst[0] = src[0] & 0xFE;
dst[1] = ((src[0]       ) << 7) | ((src[1]       ) >> 1);
dst[2] = ((src[1]       ) << 7) | ((src[2]       ) >> 1);
dst[3] = ((src[2]       ) << 7) | ((src[3]       ) >> 1);
dst[4] = ((src[3]       ) << 7) | ((src[4] & 0xFC) >> 1);
dst[5] = ((src[4]       ) << 6) | ((src[5]       ) >> 2);
dst[6] = ((src[5]       ) << 6) | ((src[6] & 0xFC) >> 2);
dst[7] = ((src[6]       ) << 5) | ((src[7] & 0xFC) >> 3);
dst[8] = ((src[7] & 0x0E) << 5) | ((src[7] & 0x01) << 3);
```

(Useless masks omitted.)

Comment: Doesnt src[0] & oxFE result in either 0 or 1. Doesnt it get rid of all other binary values. Also I dont understand how you can insert to position 100 as there are only 72 bits total.

Comment: Re "*Doesnt src[0] & oxFE result in either 0 or 1.*", No. `& 1` would do that. /// Re "*Doesn't it get rid of all other binary values*", Yes. All bits not set in 0xFE aka 0b11111110 are cleared, so bit 0 is cleared

Comment: 100 octal = 64 decimal. Note how the digits of the positions go from 0-7 instead of 0-9

Comment: So I changed the code a bit since dst[0] needs to be the one with with indexes of 0,1 and 2 so the whole thing needs to be in reverse. But I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: mine looks like, (*pH).bits[0] = (pBits[0])<< 4 | ((pBits[0] & 0x10) << 3); I just started learning bitwise. Is there something wrong with this

Comment: If the bytes are reversed, just change `src[x]` to `src[7-x]` and `dst[x]` to `dst[8-x]`

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the input array as a 64-bit int to make it faster. Suppose the input and output values are like this

```
array  = aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc dddddddd eeeeeeee ffffffff gggggggg hhhhhhhh
newArr = aaaaaaa0 abbbbbbb bccccccc cddddddd deeeeee0 eeffffff ffggggg0 ggghhhh0 hhh0h000
```

Then you can get the desired result using this way

```
uin64_t src = htobe64(*(uint64_t*)array); // operate on big endian
uint64_t* dst = (uint64_t*)newArr;

*dst  = (src & 0xFE00'0000'0000'0000) >> 0; // aaaaaaa
*dst |= (src & 0x01FF'FFFF'FC00'0000) >> 1; // abbbbbbbbccccccccddddddddeeeeee
*dst |= (src & 0x0000'0000'03FF'F800) >> 2; // eeffffffffggggg
*dst |= (src & 0x0000'0000'0000'07F0) >> 3; // ggghhhh
*dst  = be64toh(*dst); // convert back to the native endian
newArr[8] = ((array[7] & 0x0E) << 4) | ((array[7] & 0x01) << 3); // hhh0h000
```

To avoid strict aliasing you can change to memcpy to copy from `array` to `src` and from `dst` to `newArr`

Of course you may need to align the input and output arrays for better performance. On many modern architectures it's also a must

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
__declspec(align(8)) uint8_t array[8];        // 64-bit array
__declspec(align(8)) uint8_t newArr[9];
#else
uint8_t array[8] __attribute__((aligned(8))); // 64-bit array
uint8_t newArr[9] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
#endif
```

On modern x86 with [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation_instruction_set) you can use the new [bit deposit instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) to get the first 8 bytes directly

```
uint64_t src;
memcpy(&src, &array, sizeof src); // avoid strict aliasing
uin64_t src = htobe64(src);

uint64_t dst = _pdep_u64(src >> 4,
 //   aaaaaaa0 abbbbbbb bccccccc cddddddd deeeeee0 eeffffff ffggggg0 ggghhhh0
    0b11111110'11111111'11111111'11111111'11111110'11111111'11111110'11111110);
                        //   hhh0h000
newArr[8] = _pdep_u32(src, 0b11101000);

*dst  = be64toh(*dst); // convert back to the native endian
memcpy(&newArr, &dst, sizeof dst); // avoid strict aliasing
```